# Getting row title from table view in titanium alloy

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a tableview called tableview, and I am trying to get the title of the cell that has been clicked. However it is returning null. See code snippet below.

```
 $.tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Clicked index: ' + e.index);
```

//e index works.

```
             var myText = e.rowData;
             alert(e.rowData.title);

        //returns null


    });
```

If I do consolel.log(e) to find out what is thrown back fron the callback method, i get the following output:

```
[INFO] :   Clicked index: 0
[INFO] :   {
[INFO] :       bubbles = 1;
[INFO] :       cancelBubble = 0;
[INFO] :       detail = 0;
[INFO] :       index = 0;
[INFO] :       row = "[object TiUITableViewRow]";
[INFO] :       rowData = "[object TiUITableViewRow]";
[INFO] :       searchMode = 0;
[INFO] :       section = "[object TiUITableViewSection]";
[INFO] :       source = "[object TiUITableViewRow]";
[INFO] :       type = click;
[INFO] :       x = 167;
[INFO] :       y = 37;
[INFO] :   }
```

I suspect the title is nested within RowData, but I have no idea how to access the data in the object.

```
            var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
                    width : '100%',
                    height : 'auto'
                });
                var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                    image : "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (data[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + Ti.Facebook.accessToken,
                    top : 0,
                    left : 0,
                    width : 100,
                    height : 100
                });
                var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                    text : albumTitle,
                    top : 0,
                    left : 110,
                    width : 'auto',
                    height : 'auto'
                });
                row.add(image);
                row.add(title);
                rows.push(row);
```

xml I have set the table view id to tableview.

using JSON.stringify, here is what's been outputted for each object:

```
[INFO] :   row data
[INFO] :   {"horizontalWrap":true,"width":"100%","height":"auto"}
[INFO] :   row
[INFO] :   {"horizontalWrap":true,"width":"100%","height":"auto"}
[INFO] :   source
[INFO] :   {"horizontalWrap":true,"width":"100%","height":"auto"}
[INFO] :   section
[INFO] :   {"horizontalWrap":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a new property into the var row object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stringify the object to see which properties it has

```
JSON.stringify(e.rowData);
```

Comment: hi its printing this out {"horizontalWrap":true,"width":"100%","height":"auto"} . Seems to be printing that out for source, and row. I have no idea where the title is

Comment: if you can access your tableView, you could just use the getIndex method, which returns a TableViewIndexEntry. This one contains title, and id as properties

Comment: Solved the problem. I had to add a new property in var row called "titleofRow", the rowData was referencing that object, which currently has 2 properties; width/height.